# Get last result back for each post_id

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am using a `mysqlnd 5.0.12-dev` db as my backend and I would like to get back, the last row in `wp_productprofitability` for each post_id.

I have the following setup:

`wp_post`:

```
+----+--------------+
| ID | title        |
+----+--------------+
| 10 | My Product 1 |
+----+--------------+
| 11 | My Product 2 |
+----+--------------+
| 6  | My Product 3 |
+----+--------------+
```

`wp_productprofitability`

```
+---------+-------------------+---------------------+
| post_id | daily_grossProfit | created_at          |
+---------+-------------------+---------------------+
| 10      | 3.5               | 2018-06-18 07:36:00 |
+---------+-------------------+---------------------+
| 11      | 4                 | 2018-06-17 07:35:00 |
+---------+-------------------+---------------------+
| 10      | 5                 | 2018-06-16 07:34:00 |
+---------+-------------------+---------------------+
| 11      | 7                 | 2018-06-17 07:36:00 |
+---------+-------------------+---------------------+
| 10      | 5                 | 2018-06-15 07:36:00 |
+---------+-------------------+---------------------+
| 6       | 3.6               | 2018-06-12 07:34:00 |
+---------+-------------------+---------------------+
| 10      | 2                 | 2018-06-14 07:32:00 |
+---------+-------------------+---------------------+
| 6       | 6                 | 2018-06-13 07:31:00 |
+---------+-------------------+---------------------+
```

**Expected Result:**

```
+----+--------------+---------+-------------------+---------------------+
| ID | title        | post_id | daily_grossProfit | created_at          |
+----+--------------+---------+-------------------+---------------------+
| 10 | My Product 1 | 10      | 3.6               | 2018-06-18 07:36:00 |
+----+--------------+---------+-------------------+---------------------+
| 11 | My Product 2 | 11      | 4                 | 2018-06-17 07:36:00 |
+----+--------------+---------+-------------------+---------------------+
| 6  | My Product 3 |  6      | 5                 | 2018-06-16 07:34:00 |
+----+--------------+---------+-------------------+---------------------+
```

Atm I only get the following result back for the following query:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    wp_posts p
INNER JOIN wp_productprofitability m ON
    m.post_id = p.ID
WHERE
    m.created_at =(
    SELECT
        MAX(u.created_at)
    FROM
        wp_productprofitability u
)
ORDER BY
    m.daily_grossProfit
DESC
```

**Current Result:**

```
+----+--------------+---------+-------------------+---------------------+
| ID | title        | post_id | daily_grossProfit | created_at          |
+----+--------------+---------+-------------------+---------------------+
| 10 | My Product 1 | 10      | 3.6               | 2018-06-18 07:36:00 |
+----+--------------+---------+-------------------+---------------------+
| 11 | My Product 2 | 11      | 4                 | 2018-06-17 07:36:00 |
+----+--------------+---------+-------------------+---------------------+
```

Any suggestions how to get for each post_id the last occurance?

I appreciate your replies!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close.  You just need a correlation clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM wp_posts p INNER JOIN
     wp_productprofitability pp
     ON pp.post_id = p.ID
WHERE m.created_at = (SELECT MAX(pp2.created_at)
                      FROM wp_productprofitability pp2
                      WHERE pp2.post_id = pp.post_id
                     )
ORDER BY pp.daily_grossProfit DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

I would phrase your query using of your table to a subquery which finds the most recent record in `wp_productprofitability` for each `post_id`:

```
SELECT
    t1.ID,
    t1.title,
    t2.post_id,
    t2.daily_grossProfit,
    t2.created_at
FROM wp_post t1
INNER JOIN wp_productprofitability t2
    ON t1.ID = t2.post_id
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT post_id, MAX(created_at) AS max_created_at
    FROM wp_productprofitability
    GROUP BY post_id
) t3
    ON t2.post_id = t3.post_id AND t2.created_at = t3.max_created_at;
```

See Gordon's answer for a correction to your exact query.  Basically, you need to add logic to the subquery which restricts each record in `wp_productprofitability` to the latest for each `post_id`.  But I would not use a correlated subquery here, and a join would probably outperform it.